# How can the status be separated for each button in the card method?

Tags: javascript, jsx

I have used a map in my **jsx** file and when I click on a button, all the buttons in the component are changed.

```
{users.map(user => (
          <div className="Profile-block" key={user.userId}>
            <div className="Profile">
              <Avatar
                alt={user.userName}
                src={ConstantsList.GET_PROFILEPIC_BY_USERID + user.userId}
                sx={{ width: 36, height: 36 }}
              />
              <div className="Suggestion-Profile-Name-Block">
                <div className="Suggestion-Profile-Name">{user.userName}</div>
                <div className="Profile-Account-Name">{user.name}</div>
                <div className="Suggestion-Profile-Desc">Recommendation for you</div>
              </div>
            </div>
              {isSubscribed === 1 ? (
                <UnfollowButton 
                otherUserId={user.userId}
                ChangeSubscriptionState={ChangeSubscription}
              />
              ) : (
                <FollowButton 
                otherUserId={user.userId}
                ChangeSubscriptionState={ChangeSubscription}/>
              )}
          </div>
))}
```

**ChangeSubscription function**.

```
function ChangeSubscription() {     
    isSubscribed === 1 ? setIsSubscribed(0) : setIsSubscribed(1)   
}
```

**Follow button**

```
const FollowButton = ({ 
   otherUserId, ChangeSubscriptionState }) => {   
       const handleFollow = async () => {     
           try {       
               await AddFollower(otherUserId);       
               ChangeSubscriptionState();     
           } 

           catch (error) {}   };    
      
       return (  <div><button className="FollowButton" onClick=. 
            {handleFollow}>         Follow       </button>     
             </div>
       ); 
};
```

separate state for each button[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjijl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k852.png)

Comment: What happens in ChangeSubscription? And what are the contents of Follow Button? 
The template itself looks valid to me, I think the issue is inside of ChangeSubscription. Could you create a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for your issue?

Comment: `function ChangeSubscription() {
    isSubscribed === 1 ? setIsSubscribed(0) : setIsSubscribed(1)
  }` and Follow button `const FollowButton = ({ otherUserId, ChangeSubscriptionState }) => {
  const handleFollow = async () => {
    try {
      await AddFollower(otherUserId);
      ChangeSubscriptionState();
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="FollowButton" onClick={handleFollow}>
        Follow
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};` sorry but I will not be able to correctly reproduce the data on stackblitz bcs i have a lot of data and nda

Comment: Please add all details [inside](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78191849/edit) the question. Comments are not meant to dump code in

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `isSubscribed` inside of the component where you map all of the users, and it is not tied in any way to the specific user.
What you can do here is add a parameter `isSubscribe` to the specific user

```
const users = [{ <other user parameters>
                  isSubscribed: false   }];
```

And then change the `isSubscribed` for the specific user on click.

```
{user.isSubscribed === 1 ? (
                <UnfollowButton 
                otherUserId={user.userId}
                 ChangeSubscriptionState={() => 
                 ChangeSubscription(user.userId)}
              />
              ) : (
                <FollowButton 
                otherUserId={user.userId}
                ChangeSubscriptionState={() => 
                ChangeSubscription(user.userId)}/>
              )}
```

And in `ChangeSubscription` just find a user that you need to update subscription status and update it.
And make sure that the [object is updated properly](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state).

Answer (score 0):

I am rewrite ChangeSubscription to

```
const ChangeSubscription = (userId) => {
 setUsers(prevUsers => prevUsers.map(user => {
   if (user.userId === userId) {
     return { ...user, isSubscribed: user.isSubscribed === 1 ? 0 : 1 };
   }

   return user;
}));};
```

and realization this too:

```
{user.isSubscribed === 1 ? (
 <UnfollowButton 
   otherUserId={user.userId} 
   ChangeSubscriptionState={() => 
    ChangeSubscription(user.userId)}
 />
) : (
  <FollowButton otherUserId={user.userId}
   ChangeSubscriptionState={() => 
     ChangeSubscription(user.userId)}
  />
)}
```